# HashMap can keep always the same order?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I want to know if my `HashMap` collection will be always on the same order

```
        Map<Integer, Long> map = new HashMap<Integer, Long>(0);

        for(Integer key : users) {
            map.put( key , (long) 0 );
        }

        for( ... ){
            ...
            if( ... ) ){
                map.put( t.get(key) , map.get(key) + 1);
            }
        }
```

I send this collection to `javascript` with `ajax`

```
                    $.each( jsonData[i].totalMap , function(key, value) {
                        rows.push(value);
                    });
```

will have always the same order of the element of the `Map` as i put them in my controller ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case? If you need to rely on this behaviour but you do not require a specific ordering, I suspect your design may be flawed in some way. Besides the answers posted, there are also `SortedMap`s

Comment: for safety i will use `LinkedHashMap` because the same order when i Initialize my map in controller I want it when i iterate over my map in javascript code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a LinkedHashMap, the order will be kept (i.e., by default, the keys will always be iterated in the same order they were inserted into the Map).

Comment: Thanks man :) for safety i will use `LinkedHashMap` because the same order when i Initialize my map in controller I want it when i iterate over my map in `javascript` code.

Answer (score 1):

If the keys and values are always the same, the map size is the same, and the `HashMap` is initialized in the same way, then yes. However for guaranteed iteration order, use a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: On a given system. :). The same instance can have a different hashcode on a different machine

Comment: Exactly, on a given VM/version.

Comment: @Kayaman - Nope.  For some classes, you will typically get different hashcodes each time you run the application.  (Same hardware, JVM version, etc.)

Comment: @StephenC True, but here the Integer/Long would be deterministic on a given system. Not that I would ever trust or recommend others to trust that ;)

Comment: thanks man for your help for safety i will use `LinkedHashMap` because the same order when i Initialize my map in controller I want it when i iterate over my map in `javascript` code.

Comment: For the `Integer` class the hashcode is specified to be the same as the wrapped value.  You *can* trust that.  But `Integer` is unusual in this respect.